# Do the continuously differentiable functions form an integral domain?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be two real valued continuously differentiable functions with domain $[a,b]$ where $f(x)g(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Can it be concluded that $f$ and $g$ are individually zero functions?

Comment: And your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are only differentiable, even $C^\infty$, then no, as you can see from the answers. If they are analytic, then it's more interesting.

Answer (score 7):

No. Consider the functions over $[-1,1]$ 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{for $-1\le x\le 0$}\\
e^{-1/x^2} & \text{for $0<x\le 1$}
\end{cases}
\qquad
g(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2} & \text{for $-1\le x<0$}\\
0 & \text{for $0\le x\le 1$}
\end{cases}
$$

The functions are actually of class $C^{\infty}$.

The assertion is true for the analytic functions.

---

Analytic functions on a closed real interval are actually, by definition, analytic in an larger open interval. Such functions can be thought as complex analytic functions on an open connected set of the complex plane. These functions have a very pleasant property: if the set of zeros of an analytic function has an accumulation point, then the function is the constant zero.

If $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions on the region (open connected set) $\Omega$, and $fg=0$, then $Z(f)\cup Z(g)=\Omega$. Thus at least one of the two sets (where $Z(f)=\{z\in\Omega:f(z)=0\}$) has an accumulation point, or their union wouldn't be open.

Comment: Can you sketch the proof for the analytic case, if you want?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Feel free to improve the proof.

Comment: I wish I could improve it, but it's already very nice. Thank you for adding it. (I wonder why someone downvoted...?)

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=(x-\dfrac{a+b}{2})^2$ if $a\leq x\leq \dfrac{a+b}{2}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $\dfrac{a+b}{2}\leq x\leq b$.

Let $g(x)=0$ if $a\leq x\leq \dfrac{a+b}{2}$ and $g(x)=(\dfrac{a+b}{2}-x)^2$ if $\dfrac{a+b}{2}\leq x\leq b$.

Note that $f$ and $g$ meet all your requirements but not identically $0$.

Comment: There's a downvoter who apparently doesn't like correct answers. `:-(`

Comment: I am a first year undergrad, I do not know anything about analytic functions right now, so maybe my answer is weaker than yours :(

Comment: The remark about analytic functions is only tangential, I added it for completeness. Your answer is straight to the point and correct (deserving +1). By the way, also mine was downvoted.

Comment: Upvoted your answer as I can learn a lot from it actually. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Answer:**
Consider $$f:[0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$as$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & 0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
      (\frac{1}{2}-x)^2 & \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1 
   \end{cases}$$

And$$g:[0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$as$$g(x)=\begin{cases} 
    (\frac{1}{2}-x)^2 & 0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
       0& \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1 
   \end{cases}$$ then $$f.g=0$$ but neither $f=0$ nor $g=0$

Comment: This is just the same answer given in a more general form by Landon Carter.

Comment: i didn't look at answer. i was typing during that period